# Absolute value squared of the sum of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, products

How can I continue the following term, in order to get a efficient way to compute it.
$$|\sum_{l}z_{l}|^{2}=\sum_{l}z_{l}\overline{\sum_{l}z_{l}}=\sum_{l}|z_{l}|^{2}+\sum_{l \neq k}z_{l}\overline{z_{k}}$$
The second term is squared in terms of time of calculation.

Thanks

Comment: As the rabbit said, that depends a good deal on where you want to get to...

Comment: @Macavity see my edit please

Comment: The LHS has $n$ additions and one multiplication with conjugate. I don’t think it gets better than that. Certainly the current “simplification” or expansion is considerably more expensive computationally.